# In search of an angle

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to get a totally random angle from only knowing two points?

I'm trying to think out of a way to calculate that purple angle by only knowing the blue and purple points, drew up some triangles but didn't really help that much.. yet. The two points and random, so they are not fixed, therefore I need to find a general equation. Any ideas?
[image: That nasty purple angle!]

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you know the equations or slopes of the green lines?

Comment: Nope, nothing but the two points.

Comment: You can have infinitely many pairs of parallel lines passing through those two points. So the purple angle can have any value, according to the slope you choose. Perhaps the green lines should form a 45 degree angle with the brown line?

Comment: The problem is that the green lines can have any degrees aswell, I can't force them to have a specific angle.

Answer (score 0):

Two points determine a line, so the red line can be literally any line in the plane.  The green lines can be a line of any slope as long as it passes through $P(X_1,X_2)$?  This angle can be anything you want then.  This question is not well posed as it is written.

Comment: We know both points' coordinates therefore we can calculate the white triangle's every side and angle, does that help a bit?

Comment: But the green lines could be rotated through any angle you want, right?  Perhaps I am still not understanding.

Comment: We don't know the green lines' angle, but we know that the blue point is ON the green line, the other green line is just a copy of the original one.